# Sharding and Cloud computing

Tags: database, cloud-computing, sharding

I've read that Facebook uses this technique DB [sharding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29) to manage its data volume and that the idea of cloud computing is elastic resources.  So I'm wondering does the cloud instance take care of sharding for you automatically?  Or do you still have to do that part manually?  And if you do have to do it manually - then the DB doesn't seem very elastic to me.

Comment: Doesn't Cassandra auto shard?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it fails to demonstrate a minimal understanding of the techniques or technologies underlying the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can have automatic sharding - try out [ScaleBase](http://www.scalebase.com) (disclosure - I work there). You can install it on any cloud environment (or physical environment). 
BTW - Sharding is not something that any RDBMS provides - Oracle and MS-SQL solutions are not sharding - and at least Oracle's RAC solution doesn't really scale, nor does it run on cloud environments. MySQL has MySQL cluster - which does scale, but of course it's not free...

Comment: had a look at ScaleBase -- looks good -- is it open source?

Comment: Sounds awesome!

Answer (score 7):

Sharding in practice is complicated because its rarely possible to automatically (and thus elastically in the cloud) partition your DB to load balance queries effectively. In practice you always land up with hot zones and one of the few ways around is to architect the db schema anticipating such hot zones (which is something cloud elasticity won't give you).

The other problem with sharding is the loss of availability of a shard on failure of the node carrying the shard. Typically, you have to give up either strict consistency or availability when you are sharding. You may want to look at [Brewer's CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) which points out the trade-offs you *have* to make when building a distributed system. In practice, distributed systems tend to get complicated with intertwined systems with different availability and consistency properties.

Bottomline... there's little automatic here. Proper design of distributed components can get you very far.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not of the cloud instance but of the DBMS. Oracle & SQL Server do it by free MySQL uses plugins.

You can use this on any kind of app not just cloud based ones.